# Make the Button's Width same with the Browser Width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have a Button Group that looks like this:

[image]

I want to make the button's width to be dynamic, the same width with the browser.

```
<div id="opacnavigation" class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">       
    <div id="opacnavigation-btn" class="btn-group">                      
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ">
            <i class="icon-home"></i>
            Home                    
        </button>        
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">        
            <i class="icon-comment"></i>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                About the Library                                         
            </a>            
            <b class="caret"></b>                
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Library Hours</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Board of Visitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Department and Staff</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Direction Maps</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Equipment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Floor Plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Information and Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Mission and Vision</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ">
            <i class="icon-question-sign"></i>   
            Help
        </button>                                       
   </div> 
</div>
```

How will I do this through media queries using CSS?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 608px){
    ....???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" style="width: 100%;"> //etc </button
```

But your div will need to also be as wide as the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
<input type="button" style="width: 100%;"/>
```

Also, be sure to do the same for your div

Answer (score 0):

Use width =100% for your button style

Answer (score 0):

MAKE PARENT `DIV` WIDTH AS  100%

AND THEN MAKE `BUTTON WIDTH 100%`

```
<DIV STYLE="WIDTH:100%">
<input type="button" style="width: 100%;"/>
<input type="button" style="width: 100%;"/>
<input type="button" style="width: 100%;"/>
</DIV>
```